# Regex - any alphabet except "e"

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make a regular expression for any alphabets except "e"
This is what I came up with -

```
/([a-d]|[f-z])+?/i
```

- The above regex doesn't match "e" which is good.
- It matches for "amrica"
- But it also match "america" but it shouldn't because of the "e" in america

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Java or JavaScript?

Comment: Javascript. But regex is same for both right?

Comment: "E" isn't an alphabet, it's a letter.

Comment: Java and JS regexps differ greatly. In Java, I'd use `s.matches("(?i)[a-z&&[^e]]+")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the anchors `^` (beginning of the string) and `$` (end of the string); otherwise your pattern can partially match any string as long as it contains an alphabet other than *e*:

```
/^[a-df-z]+$/i.test("america")
// false

/^[a-df-z]+$/i.test("amrica")
// true

/^[a-df-z]+$/i.test("e")
// false
```

Comment: Damn, you are right! Give me 9 minutes to be able to accept this answer. I was just learning regex now, and i was wondering where to use the ^ and $ characters. Sometimes they also use word boundary (\b) at the beginning and end of a regex expression.

Comment: @Adam Sometimes, "they" also use *lookarounds*: [`/^(?:(?!e)[a-z])+$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/41UWEk/1/).

Answer (score 17):

**Modern solution**

With the adoption of the [`v` flag](https://v8.dev/features/regexp-v-flag), JavaScript regex patterns now support [character class union, intersection and subtraction.](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-class-operations.html) In this case, [character class subtraction](https://v8.dev/features/regexp-v-flag#difference) is necessary:

```js
var rx = /^[[a-zA-Z]--[eE]]+$/v;
var strs = ['america','e', 'E', 'world','hello','welcome','board','know'];
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s, "=>", rx.test(s));
}
```

So, `[[a-zA-Z]--[eE]]+` matches one or more occurrences of any letter from the A-Z and a-z ranges with the exception of `e` and `E`.

See also more about [*Intersection with `&&`*](https://v8.dev/features/regexp-v-flag#intersection) and [*Union*](https://v8.dev/features/regexp-v-flag#union).

**Legacy solution**

You may use `[a-z]` character class, but *restrict* it with a [*negative lookahead*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!e)`, group this pattern with a grouping construct `(?:...)` and add the anchors around the pattern:

```
/^(?:(?!e)[a-z])+$/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/41UWEk/1/).

This technique will work in all regex flavors that support lookaheads. Note in Java and some other languages, you may use [*character class subtraction*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html), but it is not supported by JS RegExp (nor by Python `re`). E.g., in Java, you could use `s.matches("(?i)[a-z&&[^e]]+")`.

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(?!e)[a-z])+` - 1 or more characters from `a-z` and `A-Z` range BUT `e` and `E`
- `$` - end of string anchor
- `i` - case insensitive modifier.

JS demo:

```js
var rx = /^(?:(?!e)[a-z])+$/i;
var strs = ['america','e', 'E', 'world','hello','welcome','board','know'];
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s, "=>", rx.test(s));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of alternative answers are:

1. Use a lookahead:

   ```
   /^((?=[a-z])[^e])+$/i
   ```

This is first checking that the next character is a letter, and *then* checks that it's not an `e` (or `E`).

This is valid regex syntax in JavaScript, but is less performant than the accepted answer.

2. Use set intersection:

   ```
   /^[[a-z]&&[^e]]+$/i
   ```

This is matching characters in the *set intersection* of "`a-z`" and "not `e`".

This is **not valid syntax in JavaScript**. However, it is equally performant as the accepted answer. It's only valid syntax in various other regex "flavours" such as Java, Perl, PHP, Python and Ruby.

3. Use set subtraction:

   ```
   /^[[a-z]--[e]]+$/i
   ```

This is matching characters in the *set  subtraction* of "`a-z`" and `e`.

This is **not valid syntax in JavaScript**. However, it is equally performant as the accepted answer. It's only valid syntax in various other regex "flavours" such as Python and .Net. (Syntax also varies slightly, e.g. `-` vs `--`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can also add Capital in reg use this:

```
^[a-df-zA-DF-Z]+$

i.test("America")
// false

i.test("Amrica")
// true

i.test("e")   or  i.test("E") 
// false
```

Please refer many online website to learn regex creation Step by Step
https://regex101.com

Comment: `/i` makes the regex case insensitive

Answer (score 0):

why not step through each character in the word?

```
 [i for i in strs if 'e' not in i]
```