# C# Regular Expression to allow any 5 alphanumeric characters except for 'o' or 'i' (any case)

Tags: c#

I can either validate 5 alphanumeric characters or disallow 'o' or 'i', but not both.  Please help.
Current property attribute in the view model (I don't want to write custom function).

```
[RegularExpression(@"[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}", ErrorMessage = "*It must contain 5 letters or number, no 'i' or 'o'.")]
```

//Works to disallow 'o' or 'i', but can't integrate onto current expression.

```
[RegularExpression(@"[^ioIO]"...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex - any alphabet except "e"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44771741/regex-any-alphabet-except-e)

Comment: Can't you use [a-hj-np-zA-HJ-NP-Z0-9]?

Comment: @canton7 Are you sure? What about `abicd`? Perhaps you meant `^((?![iIoO])[a-zA-Z0-9]){5}$`

Comment: @NetMage oops I read it as "allow o or i, but not both"

Comment: What does this have to do with `qregularexpression`? Are you using QT?

Answer (score 1):

.Net supports subtraction in character classes for exclusion, so use:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9-[iIoO]]{5}$", ErrorMessage = "*It must contain 5 letters or number, no 'i' or 'o'.")]
```

Comment: I copied everything between the quotes and now it doesn't allow the basic 5 alphanumeric characters - it breaks it.

Comment: @Monk Make sure you have copied exactly and it should work. As far as I know, this has always been in .Net. See [Regex Tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5ba-zA-Z0-9-%5biIoO%5d%5d%7b5%7d%24&i=abcde).